# Why is Jquery linking this websit has the different effects with chrome addClass ，ff from IE7？

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

the problem is Why Jquery linking this websit has the different  effects  with chrome addClass ，ff from  IE7,  the website is (http://static.geewax.org/checktree/index.html).
With the Brower Chrome/FF,we can get the normal effect ,get we want,but with the IE7,the effect is different,the checkbox image is disappear,why?
The website achieve the checktree.
we can get jquery-1.2.6.min.js,checktree.css and jquery.checktree.js from the websit source code.
My problem is how can I get the effect with IE7 as the same as with chrome/ff?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style to your page and you should see the same layout in IE7.

```
ul.tree li { clear: left; }
```

Comment: yes,you are right.But it's just the character moving left,the checkbox and image can't be seen,why?